# Creating an Multi-Dimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP, and I'm looking to do a fairly simple operation related to array manipulation. This is the initial array i'm working with:

```
$Orders = array(    0 => array("Client" => "John Doe", "Product" => "Chairs",
                                "Ammount" => "14"),
                    1 => array("Client" => "John Doe", "Product" => "Chairs",
                                "Ammount" => "12"),
                    2 => array("Client" => "John Doe", "Product" => "Chairs",
                                "Ammount" => "18"));
```

This is the array I want to get by the end of the operation:

```
$Orders2 = array(0 => array("Client" => "John Doe", "Product" => "Chairs",
                                "Ammount" => array("14", "12", "18")
                                ));
```

As you can see the newly created array ($Orders2) is the result of a transformation of $Orders, it groups all the orders by client. I have a few ideas on how to do this, however it feels that each solution I come across is a bit to complex. Any ideas on how to provide a simple solution?

Comment: you want to add amount array to existing array (`$orders`) ?

Comment: Is this a static array? How are you getting this data? Is this from a SQL query?

Comment: This is a static array. I want to create an entirely new array

Comment: My biggest doubt is how to creat the array inside the array inside the array